# Most of the new graduates ........ to do master degree

Tags: word-request

Which one(s) of the following words would be appropriate to state that there is trend  among new graduates that they prefer to do master degree because of competing job market these days. They think it is reasonable, not because they like it or creating a habit.

> Nowadays, most of the new graduates  ........ to do master degree for
>   better prospects in  their later lives.

have a tendency / tend to

incline to

prone to

show a proclivity to

succumb to

or any other word

Comment: many new grads choose?

Comment: @WillowRex I think it works simply.. Do you think using other options I suggested, such as "tend to",  would be totally wrong?

Comment: They are not totally wrong. I could make an answer for you, but just wanted the simple answer to be noted. "Succumb" is not right. (1 - fail to resist (pressure, temptation, or some other negative force). or 2- die)  Google dictionary

Answer (score 2):

> Nowadays, most of the new graduates ........ to do master degree for
>   better prospects in their later lives.

Might be better as: Nowadays, most of the new graduates ....(choose).... to do **a** Master's Degree for better **job or career** prospects in their later lives.

> have a tendency / tend to

good choice

> (have a inclin**ation** to /) **are** incline**d** to

good choice, please note spelling correction

> **are** prone to

good choice, please note added word

> show a proclivity to

not a good choice

Proclivity is defined as a tendency to do something, especially something you shouldn’t. (Your Dictionary)

> succumb to

not a good choice

"Succumb" is not right. (1 - fail to resist (pressure, temptation, or some other negative force). or 2- die) Google dictionary

Comment: Thank you.  When I wrote this sentence , I was taught I should not use "tend to" because it sounds like it is a habit that people  do it often..I can understand  the sense of " choice that is done regularly" the word  "to tend" conveys too..Do you think there is difference between " tend to" and  " incline to "  for the sentence?

Comment: @Mrt I think they are more formal, less casual. You might write the sentence that way, or express it in a business meeting, but in casual conversation, "choose" works simply.

Comment: @Mrt  I tend to like history. I tend to wash most of the dishes in our home. The word 'incline' doesn't fit in those examples easily. "I am inclined to enjoy history."  "I am more inclined to enjoy history over comedy in literature." "I am not inclined to wash dishes, but I must."

Comment: so your examples with " to incline" are correct , aren't they or you try to prove they do not make a sense.

Comment: @Mrt Your sentence works with both  tend to or incline to. This is hard in comments. Would you like to chat about it? We could move to a chatroom.

Comment: sure how to begin chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52892/mrt-and-willow